# Error "execution reverted: ERC721: invalid token ID" when trying to create NFT

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, nft, remix, openzeppelin

I am trying to create a smart contract that gives the user an NFT in exchange of some MATIC tokens in the Polygon testnet. I am using Remix IDE and the environment used for teh deployment is the "Injected Provider - Metamask". When I deploy the smart contract, the MATIC token transaction happens succesfully, but my Metamask account doesn´t recieve any NFT. When I try to use the "ownerOf" function the terminal answers with the following error:

```
call to ERC721.ownerOf errored: Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted: ERC721: invalid token ID"
```

I have tried with two different contracts. This is one of them:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9; //define version

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.8.3/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.8.3/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.8.3/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.8.3/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.8.3/utils/Counters.sol";

contract Example_credential1 is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, Pausable, Ownable {

    event Log(string message);

    // Propoerty variables
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;
    //uint256 private _tokenIdCounter;

    uint256 public MINT_PRICE = 0.005 ether;
    uint256 public MAX_SUPPLY = 10000; //we define the max amount of NFTs that can be created

    // Lifecycle Methods
    constructor() ERC721("Example_credential1", "EC1") {
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    }

    //Function withdraw
    function withdraw() public onlyOwner() {
        require(address(this).balance > 0, "Balance is zero");
        payable(owner()).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }


    // Pausable Functions
    function pause() public onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }


    //Minting functions
    function safeMint(address to) public payable {
        require(msg.value >= MINT_PRICE, "not enough ether sent");
        require(totalSupply() <= MAX_SUPPLY, "No more tokens can be minted");
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to,tokenId);
    }


    // Other functions
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, uint256 batchSize)
        internal
        whenNotPaused
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId, batchSize);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```

And this is the other one. It is a simpler contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.8.3/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract Example_credential2 is ERC721 {

    uint256 public MINT_PRICE = 0.005 ether;


    uint256 public tokenCounter;
    constructor() public ERC721("Example_credential2", "EC2") {
        tokenCounter = 0;
    }

    function createCollectible(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256){
        uint256 newItemId = tokenCounter;
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
        return newItemId;
    }

}
```

I keep on getting the same error. Can you help me identify the cause and solve it?

Thank you very much in advanced

Comment: Just some feedback: declare `tokenId` like this `uint256 public tokenCounter = 1`.  In your `createCollectible` function, save gas by not creating `newItemId` and just do `_safeMint(msg.sender, tokenCounter++)` which will assign `1` as your first item's ID and will increment it at the same time.  Then `return tokenCounter`

Answer (score 0):

For contract 1, the id starts from 1. So be sure to pass the id from 1 to get ownership of the NFT.
For contract 2, the id starts from 0, so be sure to pass the id from 0 to get the ownership of the NFT

In addition, you need to call the mint function after deployment. In case of contract 2, you need to call the `createCollectible` function to get NFT, with the random string param in the Remix function, for example: `createCollectible(foo)`

After that you can call `ownerOf(0)`.

Here is my succesful test with
call createCollectible function: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x45c96fcf1b183871afc3ce20d40e47f0bccc68a201d7181caf7dfcaf7f393f25
and get the token at: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/token/0xbd96ab68b3f292b79b9ff6be4461c7ef157f08d9?a=0